# Android: Skype not initiating calls using skype URI API

Tags: java, android, skype, skypedeveloper

When trying to make a Skype call using the Skype API sometimes is just opening the application and not making the call.

I found this is happening if I have opened Skype application and pressed soft back button until getting to home screen. If i close the application using the android task manager Skype API is making the call.

This is my code:

```
    Context context = this.activity;
    SkypeUtility skypeUtility = new SkypeUtility();
    skypeUtility.initiateSkypeUri(context, "skype:myskype?call");
```

initiateSkypeUri method:

```
  public void initiateSkypeUri(Context myContext, String mySkypeUri) {
    Uri skypeUri = Uri.parse(mySkypeUri);
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, skypeUri);
    myIntent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.skype.raider", "com.skype.raider.Main"));
    myIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    myContext.startActivity(myIntent);
}
```

Does anybody had this problem and know how to fix it?